# this if statement does not change the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The if statement makes logic sense to me, if the element that was clicked 
= class.piece then execute the click method to toggle the class.

added the html. just trying to manipulate the .piece field

```
Home.HighlightBackground = function ()
{

if(element.click = $(".piece"))
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }

)}
}

<html>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                </div>



//jQuery used to create the cells and their backgrounds

var cells = $(".cell");
var colorCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
    var cell = $(cells[i]);
    var isDark = colorCount % 2 == 0;
    var isNextRow = (i + 1) % 8 == 0;
    colorCount += isNextRow ? 2 : 1;
    cell.css("background-color", isDark ? "navy" : "white");
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparision.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `element`?

Comment: that is what i cant figure out. how to store a selection from a click in a variable

Comment: In jQuery, the target of the event is in `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is:

```
$(".piece").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
});
```

To make the background color change, add CSS like:

```
.highlighted {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: i had that way. but when i did that, the class of piece would change, but the background did not.

Comment: I don't know what `Home.HighlightBackground` is. How does that get called?

Comment: its a function that is being called in the main ready function

Comment: If the class is changing but not the background, it sounds like you don't have the CSS set up correctly.

Comment: I added the jQuery to the question that is used to create the cells and their backgrounds

Comment: I've updated the answer with the CSS you need to add for the class.

Comment: That is exactly what I have and it doesn't change.

Comment: Ahh, the problem is that setting the CSS of the element overrides the CSS from the stylesheet. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Use the stylesheet to set the initial colors, with `.cell:even` and `.cell:odd`.

Comment: but i have to stay within the restrictions that have been given to us, as in i can't take anything away, only add.

Comment: In that case, use `.css()` in the `.click()` function to change the color.

Comment: You can also use `!important` in the stylesheet to override the inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("body").click(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  if(elem.hasClass("piece")){
    elem.toggleClass("highlighted");
  }
});
```

Comment: I did that and it didn't change. now it is saying element is undefined

Comment: Please provide your HTML (Add your html to the question)

Comment: @ErmineSoft Where are you getting `element` from in that function?

Comment: well i cant quite figure how to store an element selected when i click on something in a variable

Comment: @Popnoodles I though that Kyle added only part of his code, but you are right element is undefined.

Comment: Ok, you updated. Now you're using `jQuery()` when in the question `$()` is used. Also that's going a very long way round to delegate something.